# how to make recent files popup in windows 7 application

Tags: windows-7

In windows 7, notepad and similar microsoft applications can popup the list of recently used files. can i make my application have similar feature.
if possible what i need to do for that?

:Seban

Comment: You can make your application do anything you want, with a little work.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: And also, in which language you write your application?

Answer (score 0):

Save the list in a file, for example in the directory where binary is, and parse it whenever user asks for it.